# Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, .xproj

Installed the Visual Studio for Mac just now and when I go to open my .Net Core solution that was created on a windows machine I get these errors:

“Unknown Solution Item Type”

All of these errors are happening with my .xproj files.

Any ideas?

I have seen there are plenty of others with this issue doing a Google search. No solutions though to fix it though.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may have solved the issue. Searching a little deeper I found this. https://www.pein-city.info/visualstudio-for-mac-review-1/

Open terminal and run a dotnet migrate seems to work so far. I have another small issue, but I can run and build locally.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issues I was having.